# Get content in parentheses following right after string using regex in php

Tags: php, regex

I have a php file as a string, I am looking for places where certain functions are called and I want to extract the passed arguments to the function.

I need to match the following cases:
some_function_name("abc123", ['key' => 'value'])
some_function_name("abc123", array("key" => 'value'))

So far I have this, but it breaks as soon as I have any nesting conditions:

```
(function_name)\(([^()]+)\)
```

Comment: What is the desired result?

Comment: Hello, the goal is to retrieve these specific lines from a longer string (specifically a php file that I'm reading as a string. My current regex captures the first case but ignores the second which has an array inside, because of the parenthesis. Is it possible to capture both cases?

Comment: So you want some_function_name("abc123", ['key' => 'value'])  to return "abc123", ['key' => 'value'] and some_function_name("abc123", array("key" => 'value')) to return "abc123", array("key" => 'value')?

Comment: Hello, sorry if I wasn't clear enough. These are not actual functions as far as this question is concerned, but strings. I'm reading a php file as a string and I want regex that exactly targets a string like
"some_function_name("abc123", ['key' => 'value']) "  and 
"some_function_name("abc123", array("key" => 'value'))"
 what I have so far does this for the first case only.

Answer (score 0):

```
$text = "test test test test some_function_name('abc123', ['key' => 'value']) sdohjsh dsfkjh spkdo sdfopmsdfohp  some_function_name('abc123', array('key' => 'value'))";
preg_match_all('/\w+\(.*?\)(\)|!*)/', $text, $matches);
var_dump($matches[0]);
```

Is this the desired result you want?

Answer (score 0):

```
$text = "blah some_function_name('abc123', ['key' => 'value']) blah some_function_name('abc123', array('key' => 'value')) blah";
preg_match_all('/\w+\(.+?(?:array\(.+?\)|\[.+?\])\)/', $text, $matches);
var_dump($matches);
```

**Output:**

```
array(1) {
  [0]=>
  array(2) {
    [0]=>
    string(48) "some_function_name('abc123', ['key' => 'value'])"
    [1]=>
    string(53) "some_function_name('abc123', array('key' => 'value'))"
  }
}
```

**Explanation:**

```
\w+                     # 1 or more word character (i.e. [a-zA-Z0-9_])
\(                      # opening parenthesis
    .+?                 # 1 or more any character, not greedy
    (?:                 # non capture group
        array\(.+?\)    # array(, 1 or more any character, )
      |                 # OR
        \[.+?\]         # [, 1 or more any character, ]
    )                   # end group
\)                      # closing parenthesis
```

Answer (score 0):

I managed to solve it using the following pattern:

```
((\'.*?\'|\".*?\")(\s*,\s*.*?)*?\);?
```

Thanks everyone for your suggestions!